# Font awesome icons don't appear

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am using font awesome to add social media button on my website. I have follow the rule but the icon doesn't appear
this is the head of my website

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>oktavianusm</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and this is how I managed it in the body of my html

```
<div class="social-media">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i>
    </div>
```

and this is what happen when I test my code in the browser

[this is what happenwhen I do the inspect element and point the cursor on the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13XQd.png)

Comment: may be the href to fontawesome is not correct, are you using it localy or from a cdn? please check the href to fontawesome. In your browser on the resource tab of dev tools control if fontawesome.min.css is loading correctly.

Comment: Did you check if the CSS file fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/fontawesome.min.css loads in your browser?

Comment: Also please to change the last href to fontawesome with this source online from the official page: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Does the directory fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web exist and, if it does, is it in the same directory as your example file?  If not, you may want to verify the path is correct.  Since you are using google for your fonts, consider using the Font Awesome CDN option for that resource.

Comment: I am using it locally @Sigma thank you, I'll try it

Comment: I think I found the problem, when I do the inspect element again there is a warning that says
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/okta/Desktop/oktavianusm/use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css 
so, the font awesome not allowed to load by the browser right? and how I solve this? @Sigma

Comment: I think I found the problem, when I do the inspect element again there is a warning that says Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/okta/Desktop/oktavianusm/use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css so, the font awesome not allowed to load by the browser right? and how I solve this? @Jason

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the Font Awesome website at: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css.

Here is the correct stylesheet link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Was looking at using these on my web site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The link was intermittently not loading into the DOM. There was no obvious reason for it, so to get round it I added the following code to manually add the link. jQuery is used to add a link into the head. If it already exists then you just get a duplicate.

```
<!-- Font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Font awesome force load as was not loading -->
<script>
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">');
</script>
```

I know that this is not a pretty solution but it does work. I should mention that this link is for 4.7 You need to change it to whatever version you want.